# is it possible to run BigQuery command-line interface (cli) against a local BigTable emulator instance?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I would like to run the BigQuery command-line 'bq' tool as provided in the GCloud SDK against a locally running BigTable instance.

I have a locally running BigTable 'emulator' instance verified by the command-line 'cbt' tool.

I would very much like to run the BigQuery command-line tool against this local, not cloud, BigTable instance but am as of yet unable to find a means to do so.

thx,

- james

Comment: Please be advised that BigTable local emulator instance is usefull for testing your application, it is not possible to access the local instance via BigQuery( via CLI or otherwise).

Comment: thx @Verma ... understood and not entirely expected. just wanted validation. it would expedite validation and serve as a enabling developer aid to have some limited bq support for local bt instance but not a blocker per se. thx!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for an ability to locally exercise BigQuery's support for federated tables backed by Bigtable?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable

This is not something we support today but it's an interesting feature request.

Currently per https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403421/643848 there is no BigQuery emulator. I suspect that would likely be a required feature and blocking dependency  before we could support a full local version of federated BigQuery<->Bigtable.