# Are there Testconatiners for BigQuery emaulator?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, integration-testing, testcontainers, google-bigquery-java

I am working with the [Java BigQuery API Client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) and I am not sure how to write some integration tests for it.

I saw this [old StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49336013/how-can-i-make-integration-tests-with-google-cloud-bigquery) but I don't know If anything has changed since then. I can see [testcontaienrs for some of the GCloud modules](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/gcloud/), but nothing for BigQuery out of the box. Does anybody have any idea or suggestions on how to test?

If none of this is possible, I have also found the [com.google.cloud.bigquery.testing](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com.google.cloud.bigquery.testing) which will perform the actual HTTP calls. Has anybody tried it and has any feedback?